# Is there a way to count how many Kivy Clock.schedule objects there are present at runtime?

Tags: python, kivy, clock

I am new to Kivy. I am trying to create android app with two screens, whitch both display list of dynamicaly created `Buttons`. Generaly I add or remove `Button`or edit the its content and want to see changes made in it as they are happening. Here is simplified example where Button changes from column to column:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    MyListA:
    MyListB:
'''

class Content:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contentA =[]
        self.contentB = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.contentA.append(f"X{i}")
        self.change_made = 0

    def switch_to_content_A(self, content_id):
        content = self.contentB.pop(content_id)
        self.contentA.append(content)
        self.change_made = 2

    def switch_to_content_B(self, content_id):
        content = self.contentA.pop(content_id)
        self.contentB.append(content)
        self.change_made = 2

class MyListA(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        content_listA = []
        for i in c.contentA:
            content_listA.append(Button(text=str(i), on_release=lambda x, id=len(content_listA): self.switsch_to_B(id)))
            self.add_widget(content_listA[-1])

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)

    def update(self, *args):
        if c.change_made > 0:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.__init__()

    def switsch_to_B(self, content_id):
        c.switch_to_content_B(content_id)
        self.update()
        c.change_made -= 1

class MyListB(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        content_listB = []
        for i in c.contentB:
            content_listB.append(Button(text=str(i), on_release=lambda x, id=len(content_listB): self.switsch_to_A(id)))
            self.add_widget(content_listB[-1])

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)

    def update(self, *args):
        if c.change_made > 0:
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.__init__()

    def switsch_to_A(self, content_id):
        c.switch_to_content_A(content_id)
        self.update()
        c.change_made -= 1

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Content()
    MyApp().run()
```

The way I understand it script `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)` is nessesary to update the other column. However I suspect that there are multiple `schedule_interval`s created (but never killed) because my program begins to slow significaly and then freeze after a while. I am looking to see if I can detect and kill older `schedule_interval`s. Though if that is not to reason of freezing I would like to know what is.

Comment: You are scheduling calls to `update()` functions in two class `__init__()` methods, but your `update()` methods are also calling `__init__()`, so more calls to `update()` are being scheduled, which again call `__init__()`, which again schedules more calls, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes I also figured this is the main problem. However I am not sure how to remove item (Button) from the list and imidietly show it on the other list without reinitalizing both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `MyListA` to:

```
class MyListA(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)

    def update(self, *args):
        if c.change_made > 0:
            self.clear_widgets()
            content_listA = []
            for i in c.contentA:
                content_listA.append(Button(text=str(i), on_release=lambda x, id=len(content_listA): self.switsch_to_B(id)))
                self.add_widget(content_listA[-1])

    def switsch_to_B(self, content_id):
        c.switch_to_content_B(content_id)
        self.update()
        c.change_made -= 1
```

and similar for `MyListB`. Also `Content.change_made` has to be 1 or 2 for the first update to happen. If you need the first update before 0.5 seconds, yu can just add one call to `self.update()` in `__init__()`

Comment: This fixed what I was trying to achieve. Still I am curious is there way to count and print number of Clock instances present at runtime?

Comment: You can use `Clock.get_events()` to get a list of the scheduled events. And after a bit more investigation, I believe I was wrong about your code. I think `Clock.schedule_interval()` is smart enough not to duplicate scheduled events. So, I suspect your slowdown was due to executing `__init__()` over and over again.

Comment: You might be right about `__init()`. Still, I aplied this solution to the larger app and now it seems to work flawlesly (propaply just because there was no need for endless initalization). So thank you!